# How to center a html.H1 in Dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How do I center a text in html.H1 in ploty dash in python?

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([       
    html.H1('Hello Dash', style={'color': 'red', 'fontSize': 40})
         ])
```

I want to put 'Hello Dash' right in the middle of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: You can always give it an id and use CSS to center it

Comment: honestly I know nothing about html or css, guess I can't escape it after all

Comment: You could use the dash bootstrap components and use their layout components. They use a grid system which is supposedly easier to center, control the layout etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dash is generating HTML and CSS. You can see the code it produced by right clicking on the heading in your page and using 'Inspect'.

As an example, it turned 'fontSize' into CSS property 'font-size'. The CSS property to position a line of text is 'text-align' ([examples](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)). So following the same pattern, when using the 'html' method, you could refer to CSS documentation and convert the dash separated properties into camelCase when setting them in the style dictionary. Then dash will convert it back to a CSS property when rendering.

```
app.layout = html.Div([       
    html.H1('Hello Dash', style={'textAlign': 'center'})
])
```

Produces this HTML with inline CSS:

```
<div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Hello Dash</h1>
</div>
```

- See dash [layout docs](https://dash.plotly.com/layout) ('More about HTML' section)